# Finding angle with pure Geometry.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Each side of a square $ABCD$ has a length of $1$ unit. Points $P$ and $Q$ belong to $AB$ and $DA$ respectively. The perimeter of triangle $APQ$ is $2$ units. What will be the angle of $PCQ$?

I was able to do this with simple trigonometry and found it to be $45^\circ$ but the book I am reading doesn't yet talk about trigonometry or similarity of triangles so I want rather pure geometric proof which doesn't include trigonometry or similarity of triangle concepts.

Comment: Let $AQ=x,AP=y.$ Then you can find that $2x+2y=xy+2,$ which has infinitely many solutions for $0 < x,y \leq 1.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I apologize for replacing points $PQ$ with $EF$, I'm too tired to draw the picture again :)

Draw circle with center $E$ and radius $EB$ and circle with center $F$ and radius $FD$. These circles intersect segment $EF$ at points $G',G''$ These points are identical! Why? 
Because perimeter of triangle $AEF$ is 2 which is  $AB+AD=AE+EB+AF+FD=AE+EG'+AF+FG''$. It means that $EG'+FG''=EF$ and therefore $G'\equiv G''\equiv G\in EF$.

So these two circles **touch** at point $G$ as shown in the picture. Power of point $C$ with respect to both circles is equal $(CB=CD)$ and therefore it has to be on the radical axis of the circles. These circles touch at point $G$ and their radical axis is defined by the common tangent at point $G$. Becuase of that $CG$ must be tangent to both circles and, at the same time, $CG\bot EF$.

The rest is trivial: you can easily show that triangles $FCD$ and $FCG$ are congruent. The same is true for triangles $ECG$ and $ECB$. Because of that:

$$\angle ECF=\frac12\angle BCG+\frac 12\angle GCD=45^\circ$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rotate $Q$ for $90^{\circ}$ around $C$ in to new point $E$. Then $P,B,E$ are collinear and $PE = PQ$. So triangles $CQP$ and $CEP$ are congruent by (sss), so $$\angle QCP = \angle ECP = 45^{\circ}$$

Comment: You're right... And how can $PB=PQ$? Isn't that a particular case?

Comment: ..........[+1]!

Comment: @Dr.Mathva Also thank you for not voting for close down...

Comment: I don't really understand why that question should be closed or downvoted (which is the reason why I upvoted and voted not to close it)... It sometimes happens that good questions are voted to be closed...

Comment: And I must admit that your posts always impress me! Specially when the questions are similar to Olympiad questions